# Sync Checkbox visibility based on value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have two checkbox groups that I ultimately need to have one of them effect the output (visibility) of the other. Here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kEKYw/1/

So, the value from the first input (int value) should match with the value of the inputs from the second checkbox group (currently hidden) and then show them based on that selection. I feel that I'm pretty darn close, but any nudges in the right direction would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: Your example isn't clear to me as both checkbox groups contain the exact same values.  Either way, your jQuery selector isn't finding an element since you don't have any elements with the id of `wood_types`.  You might want to use the starts with or contains selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code a bit.. See comments on the code.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kEKYw/3/

```
$("#wood_typeschecklist input").change(function() {
    var destEl = this.id.split("-");
    //a. Changed selector to look for starts with selector as the 
    //checkbox value returned is wood_type-<number> 
    //which doesn't match any existing id

    //b. `.split` splits the string when it matches its 
    //separator and so it was returning 3 tokens not 2 (in,wood_types,126)
    var $matchingElem = $("li[id^=" + destEl[1] + '-' + destEl[2] + "]", $("#acf-wood_species_availability"));
    ($(this).attr("checked") !== undefined) ? $matchingElem.show() : $matchingElem.hide();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I built http://pastebin.com/mXbVgkK9 off of what you provided in addition to check if they are already "selected" on pageload - which also works great. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEKYw/5/) is what you are looking for

```
// start off by hiding the second options
$("#acf-wood_species_availability li").hide();

//add a click method to the inputs
$("#wood_typeschecklist input").click(function() {
   //verify that it's checked, if so, show the other input of the same value (and check it also) 
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#acf-wood_species_availability input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('checked', true).parents('.popular-category').show();
    }
    //if it's unchecked, hide the other input and uncheck this one
    else {
        $('#acf-wood_species_availability input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('checked', false).parents('.popular-category').hide();                            
    }   
});

//now let's add click methods to the other checkboxes in case user clicks on them, if so, we hie this checkbox and uncheck the other one.
$("#acf-wood_species_availability input").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', '').parents('.popular-category').hide();
    $('#wood_typeschecklist input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, @Vega just got here first. Thanks again!

Comment: True, but I thought you wanted to allow users to go both ways. That's why my code is a bit more complex! Cheers!